# Validate Access token in service to service authentication using azure oauth2

Tags: azure, spring-boot, authentication, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I want to enable service to service authentication in my services using spring boot and azure oauth2.I have generated access token using

https://login.microsoftonline.com//oauth2/token (POST)

I want to validate that whenever my service is hit with this access token , it should the request or throw 403.It is always throwing 403.

Hitting after putting header : Authorization -> Bearer access_token

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class WebAuthentication extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
  http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/subordinate").permitAll();
        http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated();

    }
}
```

What should be added to validate service based authentication token.(No user is involved in generating token)